# LDAP More than one negation operators in filter

Tags: filter, ldap, negation

I try to write a LDAP filter with two negations. I need all users who are not disabled AND don't belong to OU=Abt99 .

This is my filter at the moment:

`(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname={USERNAME})(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))`

I tried

`(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname={USERNAME})(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(OU=Abt99)))`

and

`(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname={USERNAME})(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)!(OU=Abt99)))`

and also

`(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname={USERNAME})(&(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(OU=Abt99))))`

nothing worked.
I've [read](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19528-01/819-0997/gdxpo/index.html) that only one filter is affected by the not operator, but there must be a way to say something like 'not this AND not that'.
Perhaps anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental form of 'not this and not that' in LDAP's prefix notation for filters is:

```
(&(!(this))(!(that)))
```

However, by de Morgan's laws, that is equivalent to 'not (this or that)', or:

```
(!(|(this)(that)))
```

which you may find clearer.